# Where am I going wrong in importing a self made python class in a self made sub package?

Tags: python, import, pycharm, python-import

Hi I'm new to python and I would appriciate a second pair of eyes on this. I am currently refactoring a project to make it extensible.

The interperter encounters an error in main.py when trying to import an object called IrishTimesEventHandler from module located in a different package:

```
from alexaevents.irish_times_event_handler import IrishTimesEventHandler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alexaevents.irish_times_event_handler'
```

Hear is a snap of my directory:

[image]

The import statment in main.py looks like this:

```
from alexaevents.irish_times_event_handler import IrishTimesEventHandler
```

- I have duplicet enteries in sys.path.
- The venv directory is listed in sys.path.
- I am using PyCharm community edition.
- I am using a Python 3.6 iterperter.

I am in the midle of refactoring using PyCharm, but as far as I can tell there are no circular dependencies.

Comment: what's the content of the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: @FlyingTeller all __init__.py files are empty. I took 'In the simplest case, __init__.py can just be an empty file', to mean that you did not need to have anything in it for an import to work, unless you wanted to package.* Is this not the case?

Comment: also, does `ìmport alexaevents` work?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Typing 'import alexaevents' dose not throw an error

Comment: @bloopiebloopie Yeah you shouldn't need to put imports in __init__.py.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue to be honest. Try deleting all `*.pyc` files and pycache directories and also do `import alexaevents` followed by `print(alexaevents.__file__)` to make sure that nothing weird is going on (old compiled pyc being loaded or there being a version of `alexaevents` somewhere else that gets loaded)

Comment: @FHTMitchell Thank you. Do you think there is anything obviously wrong with my implementation? Such as a typo, or logical error. I went over it several times since yesterday but as I am a novice I am unsure as where to look next. I also copied the files and directories into a new project to see would the problem persist. It did.

Comment: @FlyingTeller Thank you so much. I will do as you have suggested. I was unsure as where to look next.

Comment: @bloopiebloopie Does the file have a `.py` extension?

Comment: @FHTMitchell You are correct the file did not have the extension `.py`. Thank you so much for your time. I rely appreciate it.

Comment: @FlyingTeller I got an answer to my question. I just want to thank you for your time and effort. Your assistance is much appriciated.

Comment: Sometimes its that easy :D Glad it works now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you name the file name to `irish_times_event_handler.py` or `irish_times_event_handler`?

I think .py extension is required when you are importing a module

Comment: I am just seeing this now. You are correct the file name was not labelled with the extension `.py`. I don't know how I didn't see that. I just saw the icon beside the file name and assumed the file had the extension '.py' in the directory but that the IDE was not showing the extension. I changed it and it worked. When I am not so relieved/overjoyed, I will feel quite foolish. Thank you so much for your time. I rely, rely appreciate it. It’s all learning…